# Cannot access the key value inside a Redux State Object. When try to access key and value its undefined

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, redux-toolkit

[image: 1]

first time *userLogin* successfully destructuring. but when **i refresh page** *userLogin* showing everithing in there but when i console *uerInfo* undefined. Why its heappening

```
function Header() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  console.log(userLogin)// userInfo successfully showing
  console.log(userInfo)//undefined
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout());
  };
```

I expecting the value of the object key successfully. Please Help

Comment: When you refresh the page, do you have a dispatch on the same page to restore datas in Redux ?

Comment: Just curious, instead of outputting `userLogin` directly, output JSON of it: `console.log(JSON.stringify(userLogin))`

Comment: initial state is localStorage. data saved in localStorage